# What is the Cntrl-. (Control and dot/period character) key binding?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

On a new laptop with 22.04 installed I have a weird key binding on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> (Control and dot/period character). If I use it in any text window, be it gedit, emacs, firefox or chromium text input box, even with the text input tool in a gimp image, I get a lowercase `e` underscored. If I then type more characters, these appear underscored. If I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> again, the typed sequence disappears, yet with `Return` the typed sequence of characters is kept with the underscores removed.

Emacs is extra weird in showing the characters typed after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> in an extra flyout:

[image]

When asking emacs' `describe-key` function, it will never see the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd>. When asking `xev` it merely shows that <kbd>Control</kbd> and <kbd>Dot</kbd> where pressed. There is nothing in keyboard shortcuts or the keyboard setting for the window manager (Xfce4 in my case, but I get the same when running with Ubunut(Standard)).

One more pointer: Checking this little extra window on emacs with `xwininfo`, it has the name `ibus-ui-gtk3`.

Does anyone know what this is? Is there a way to figure out where the behaviour is generated, some tool to see what happens between what `xev` records and what emacs' `describe-key` sees.

Answer (score 3):

That last hint from the flyout window over emacs gives it away. Something `ibus`.

There is the program `ibus-setup` which has an `Emoji` tab where `<Control> period` is defined.

Comment: Yes this is Ibus, but perhaps GTK also implements that behavior itself, check [transient symbols for compose and dead keys in GTK programs](https://linux.codidact.com/posts/285653) *(disclaimer: it's my own content in a site I moderate)*.

Comment: Didn‘t know codidact, thanks.

Comment: Thank you for this! In RStudio, Ctrl + . is used for a very common "Go to file/function" key binding, and this was hijacking it.  <3